# Inserting values into sql node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, db2

I have this:

```
var userRegister2 = "INSERT INTO GOT (USERNAME, PASSWORD, NAME, USERID) VALUES (?)";
ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function (err, conn) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  conn.query(userRegister2, [registerDetails.username, registerDetails.password, registerDetails.name, registerDetails.userid], function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("success!")


    res.render('index.ejs')

    conn.close(function () {
    });
  });
});
```

all looks good to me, but then what happens is I get this error:

```
 SQL0117N  The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns or variables.
```

In my database table, I have only those 4 columns, so I am not sure what else to do?

Comment: You need to have the same number of parameter-markers as parameters, i.e `values(?,?,?,?)`

Comment: Try `"INSERT INTO GOT (USERNAME, PASSWORD, NAME, USERID) VALUES ?"`

Comment: @mao lol can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the code so that the number of parameter-markers matches the number of parameters.

In your case, that means `VALUES (?,?,?,?)` because you are supplying four parameters.